# I want to prove uncurry(curry(f)) = f, curry(uncurry(g)) = g with using ML

Tags: currying, ml

I have two ML functions

```
fun curry f x y = f(x, y);
fun uncurry g (x, y) = g x y;
```

And I want to prove

```
uncurry(curry(f)) = f
```

and

```
curry(uncurry(g)) = g
```

I search the search engine site, but nothing satisfied me.
Two functions that located top of this text are not clearly defined.
For example, to prove uncurry(curry(f)) = f I have to using curry function(fun curry f x y = f(x , y);) but there is not clearly defined curry.
How to prove two things?

Comment: What do you mean by "not clearly defined"? Didn't you just define those functions?

Answer (score 3):

I'll show how to demonstrate `curry (uncurry f) = f`.

```
curry (uncurry f) =                       (* by definition of uncurry *)
curry (fn (x,y) -> f x y) =               (* by definition of curry *)
fn x y -> ((fn (x,y) -> f x y) (x,y)) =   (* beta-reduction on innermost level *)
fn x y -> (f x y) =                       (* by eta-expansion *)
f
```

The other problem can be solved similarly.

Note: the functions `curry (uncurry f)` and `f` are equal in extensional sense (we accept the functional extensionality axiom, more details can be found [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55231/why-is-map-insertionsort-not-to-equal-tomap-mergesort/).